# Poll a service until I get a response or time out after certain time period

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

**Requirement**
call a service.

If that service returns data, set data to a variable. functionality over

If that service returns data = null, call that service every 20 sec on repeat until it returns data= "a list or an object" or call the service for 2 mins and stop.

**What I tried**
Need to Poll this service getUrlById(id) every 20 second, until I get the response in this.url  or time out after 6 minutes.

Tried the below solution which is not working as expected.

```
pollUrl(id) {
    interval(2000).pipe(
      timeout(600000),
      takeWhile(() => this.url)
    ).subscribe(i => {
      this.service.getUrlById(id).subscribe(res =>{
        if(res && res["result"]){
          this.url = res["result"];
        }
      })
      })
  }
```

**From Comments What I tried**

Invoked the dummy service here, [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-jones-k467).

Here dummy service returns data = null. So according to requirement I need to call the service every 20 second till 2 minutes. That is not working.

Its not necessary to use this code, I want achieve the requirement. Can have different approach.

Comment: `@user630209` see my update

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-almeida-cdlwq

Comment: The service need to call again if the response data is null. This is not working.

Comment: status: 429, statusText: "Too Many Requests"

Comment: the observable stops since there was the error

Comment: you can `retry` but it will fail again

Comment: you might want to increase the gap between request, also use  `exhaustMap` instead of `switchMap` see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `find`  operator (Finds the first value that passes some test and emits that [Docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/find)) so the Observable returned by `getUrlById` completes as soon as `response.result` is defined, as demonstrated below:

```
interval(2000)
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.service.getUrlById(id)), // <== switch subscription to `getUrlById` 
    find(x => x && x.result && x.result.length > 0),
    timeout(6 * 60 * 1000)
  )
  .subscribe(i => { })
```

here's a [LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-gagarin-d5g9w?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Optionally using [expand](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/expand) so that further requests will not be sent as long as the current hasn't been completed.

```
const api$ = this.service.getUrlById(id);

api$.pipe(
    expand(x => x && x.result && x.result.length > 0 ? EMPTY : api$.pipe(delay(2000))),
    last(), // get the result
    timeout(6 * 60 * 1000)
)
.subscribe(i => { })
```

Comment: find(x => x?.result)  - this line throw below error. Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

Comment: find((x: any) => x?.result) error while running ng serve.  error TS1109: Expression expected.
src/app/register.component.ts(420,31): error TS1005: ':' expected.

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: see my update, in fact `getUrlById` should return an actual type rather than returning type `object`

Comment: find((x: any) => x?.result)  . This is from update. Why error at this line.  ':' expected Failed to compile.

Comment: I suspect the chaining operator not working in angular 8 (not sure), please see my update

Comment: find((x: any) => x && x.result  && x.result.length>0 ).. added. It calls one time returns empty, but  no polling happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221436/discussion-between-user630209-and-rafi-henig).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use the RetryWhen operator ?

Something like: (link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/zhck3h?file=index.ts)

```
import { interval, of, throwError, zip, from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, retry, map, retryWhen, delay, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const randomCall = () => {
  const rand = Math.random() * 100;
  if (rand > 50) {
    console.log('has failed')
    throw 'error'
  } else {
    console.log('has succeed')
    return 'success';
  };
}
const source = of(1).pipe(
  map(() => randomCall()),
  take(1)
);

let retries = 5;
const example = source.pipe(
  retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
      delay(1 * 1000),
      mergeMap(error => retries-- > 0 ? of(error) : throwError('error'))
  ))
)

const subscribe = example.subscribe({
  next: val => console.log('success: ' + val),
  error: val => console.log(`retry exceeded!`)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I'd say that `timeout` operator is redundant in this case. It is supposed to throw an error if the **source** does not emit in `600000`ms, but this will never happen, since the source will emit every `2000`ms.

With this in mind, here would be my approach:

```js
interval(2000).pipe(
  switchMap(id => this.service.getUrlById(id)),
  filter(res && res["result"]),
  
  // if we got a response -> stop polling
  first(),

  // if we didn't get a response in `600000`ms -> stop polling
  takeUntil(timer(600000)),
)
```

It didn't work before probably because `takeWhile(() => this.url)` was reached before `this.url` would be populated, meaning that when the `takeWhile`'s callback function was called, `this.url` was `undefined`(ar any falsy value), so the entire stream would have completed.

Comment: Can i save  the value  res["result"] to  this.url variable at some point ?

Comment: @user630209 yes, just add a `tap(res => this.url = res["result"])` after `filter()`

Comment: why use `filer` + `first` while `find` is available?

Comment: @RafiHenig thanks for pointing out, I'd say they can be used interchangeably, although each of them can span to other use cases. For example, with `find` you have the choice to return only the **index** where the cb invoked on the value returns true. `first` can have a default value, whereas find does not.

Comment: `" timeout operator is redundant in this case. It is supposed to throw an error if the source does not emit in 600000ms, but this will never happen, since the source will emit every 2000ms.`" this is not true since filter/find will filter the unwanted values.

Comment: @RafiHenig I disagree. The way the OP had used it: `interval(2000).pipe(timeout(600000))`, it is redundant. Moreover, if `timeout` gets to do its job, it will (by default) return an error, which does not to seem to be what the OP is looking for. However, you can provide a custom observable to `timeout` which will be subscribed if the timeout's `ms` pass.

Comment: why did you prefer `takeUntil(timer(600000)),` to `timeout` which was intended just for this kind of task? both will stop the subscription.

Comment: @RafiHenig , yes but `timeout(ms)` will throw an error, whereas `takeUntil` will emit a `complete` notification. As I described before, you can also provide an observable to be subscribed when `timeout`'s `ms` pass.

Comment: @RafiHenig did not say it was anything wrong with it, I just thought a complete notification may be more appropriate

Comment: @AndreiGătej Cannot find res

Comment: This is call only once. I got the response, result is empty. It is not calling the service again.

Comment: @user630209 how does the empty result look like?

Comment: interval(2000).pipe(      switchMap(id => this.service.getUrlById(id)),      filter(res => res && res["result"] && res["result"].length > 0),      // if we got a response -> stop olling      first(),      // if we didn't get a response in `600000`ms -> stop polling     takeUntil(timer(600000)),
    ).subscribe(i => {
      console.log(i)
    }) .. this ismwhat i tried

Comment: This is the empty response, {"version":2.0,"code":4,"message":"No Record Found","result":[]}

Comment: @user630209 try adding the complete callback to “subscribe”, or try adding a “tap(console.log)” after “filter”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221492/discussion-between-user630209-and-andrei-gtej).

Answer (score -1):

Whenever polling comes up, usually the way to go is the `expand` operator, for one thing because it outrules a situation when the request takes more than your polling period and you end up with two simultaneous requests. Something like

```
of(undefined).pipe(
  expand((result) =>
    result === undefined
      ? this.service.getUrlById(id).pipe(
          map((data) => data?.result),
          switchMap((result) =>
            result !== undefined
              ? of(result)
              : of(undefined).pipe(delay(20000)),
          ),
        )
      : EMPTY,
  ),
  filter((result) => result !== undefined),
  timeout(600000),
);
```